# Django Add new record error duplicate key value violates unique constraint "" Django Id doesn't sync with database

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-postgresql

I developed a Django Application and it was working correctly, **until I did a data migration** to the database created by django migration, I migrated the data using an sql script and Pgadmin.

Now I have the database full with records but when I am trying to add new record using django form I got the below error:

> duplicate key value violates unique constraint > "learningcenters_partnerorganization_pkey"
>   DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.

taking into consideration that the available id for this table is 10.

Model:

```
class SLPAcademicRound(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45,
                            unique=True,
                            verbose_name=_('Academic Round Name'))
    code = models.CharField(max_length=5,
                            unique=True,
                            verbose_name=_('Code'))
    cycle = models.ForeignKey(
        SLPCycle,
        blank=False, null=True,
        verbose_name=_('SLP Cycle/SLP Cycle'),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    learning_center = models.ForeignKey(
        LearningCenter,
        blank=False, null=True,
        verbose_name=_('Learning Center'),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    round_date_start = models.DateField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        verbose_name=_('SLP Round Start Date')
    )
    round_date_end = models.DateField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        verbose_name=_('SLP Round End Date')
    )
    current_round = models.BooleanField(
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        verbose_name=_('Current Round')
    )
```

View:

```
class AddSLPAcademicRoundView(LoginRequiredMixin,
              GroupRequiredMixin,
              CreateView):

    template_name = 'bootstrap4/common_form.html'
    form_class = SLPAcademicRoundForm
    queryset= SLPAcademicRound.objects.all()
    group_required = ["LearningCenterManager"]


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("slp:slp_academic_round_list")


    def form_valid(self, form):
        print((form.cleaned_data))
        form.save(self.request)
        return super(AddSLPAcademicRoundView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_form_kwargs(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs(*args, **kwargs)
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
        return kwargs
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution by pg_get_serial_sequence can be used to avoid any incorrect assumptions about the sequence. This resets the sequence in one shot:

```
SELECT pg_catalog.setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('table_name', 'id'), (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table_name)+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the command

```
manage.py sqlsequencereset
```

This will give you a script to reset the table ids to normal. 
Thereafter, run the script in psql and all the table's sequences will be reset.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but it seems to reset the id to  1, I want the id to sync with the exited ids in the database. so it will continue the sequence. any suggestion?